# Canonical ways to perform host-side malloc and asynchronous host-to-device memcpy

Tags: c++, asynchronous, cuda

Say that I have a function that takes a device pointer and do something on it. However the job is more suitable for cpu, so I allocate a chunk of memory on cpu, perform some operations on the cpu memory, then copy it to gpu. Something like this:

```
void func(void *dev_ptr, cudaStream_t stream)
{
    void *host_ptr = malloc(100);
    // do something on host_ptr
    cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_ptr, host_ptr, 100, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);
    free(host_ptr);
}
```

The `free` call is dangerous here, since the memcpy is asynchronous and the copy might not be completed at the point `free` is called. I figure out that there is a callback mechanism in CUDA, so I think the following code might be more appropriate:

```
void CUDART_CB callback_free(cudaStream_t, cudaError_t, void *userData)
{
    free(userData);
}

void func(void *dev_ptr, cudaStream_t stream)
{
    void *host_ptr = malloc(100);
    // do something on host_ptr
    cudaMemcpyAsync(dev_ptr, host_ptr, 100, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);
    cudaStreamAddCallback(stream, callback_free, static_cast<void *>(host_ptr), 0);
}
```

Question:

1. Is it the canonical way to complete this task?
2. What if I want the `host_ptr` to be allocated on stack rather than on heap? I don't want to introduce unnecessary `cudaStreamSynchronize` here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AngryLettuce Never mind... just to be consistent with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree`

Answer (score 4):

To answer your questions:

1. *Is it the canonical way to complete this task?*
   To the best of my knowledge that is the only way you are going to be able to do that without an explicit synchronisation call.
2. *What if I want the `host_ptr` to be allocated on stack rather than on heap? I don't want to introduce unnecessary `cudaStreamSynchronize` here.*
   You wouldn't be introducing an unnecessary `cudaStreamSynchronize` call, you would be introducing a necessary one. The only way to stop a stack variable from going out of scope in such a case would be to block, and the correct way to block would be to call `cudaStreamSynchronize`.